# UNIX commands which use neither standard input nor standard output

Tags: unix, command

I want 3 UNIX command which use neither standard input nor standard output  .

I am still confused that a command with any redirection of using pipes is can be said as a example of not using standard input or standard output

Comment: `shutdown`, `nice`, `touch`, `mkdir`, `rm` seem to me to be candidates.

Comment: `true`, `false` and `cd` seem to meet the brief too.

Comment: `rm -i` reads stdin

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Who said anything about `-i`?  No, on a more serious note, yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"standard input"* is normally what comes from the user's keyboard, or in the case of a pipeline, what comes from the preceding process.

*"standard output"* is normally what gets sent to the screen, or in the case of a pipeline, what gets sent onto the following process.

So, you seem to be looking for commands that read no input, and produce no output. Here are some that spring to mind:

- `cd`
- `touch`
- `mkdir`
- `nice`
- `shutdown`
- `true`
- `false`